# Why can't I reference in the column list?

Tags: sql

This is my first database, I created `HOTEL`, `ROOM` and `GUEST` tables, but when I execute the `BOOKING` table, it's not working.

The error is:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table '`ROOM`'
>   that match the referencing column list in the foreign key
>   '`FK_BOOKING_ROOM`'

Scripts:

```
CREATE DATABASE HOTEL
USE HOTEL

CREATE TABLE HOTEL
(
   HolCode      varchar(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   Name     varchar(30),
   City     varchar(20) DEFAULT 'Ha noi',

   CONSTRAINT PK_HOLEL PRIMARY KEY (HolCode)
)


CREATE TABLE ROOM
(
   RoomNo       int,
   HolCode      varchar(20),
   TypeRoom     char(1)     DEFAULT 'S',
   Price        double precision,

   CONSTRAINT CHK_TYPE CHECK (TypeRoom = 'D' OR TypeRoom = 'S' OR TypeRoom = 'F'),
   CONSTRAINT CHK_PRICE CHECK (10 <= Price AND Price <= 200),
   CONSTRAINT PK_ROOM PRIMARY KEY (RoomNo, HolCode),
   CONSTRAINT FK_ROOM FOREIGN KEY (HolCode) REFERENCES HOTEL(HolCode)
)

-- TAO BANG GUEST
CREATE TABLE GUEST
(
    GuestNo     int,
    GuestName   varchar(30),
    Address     varchar(50),

    CONSTRAINT PK_GUEST PRIMARY KEY (GuestNo)
)

--TAO BANG BOOKING
CREATE TABLE BOOKING
(
    HolNo       varchar(20)     NOT NULL,
    GuestNo     int     NOT NULL,
    DateFrom    DateTime    DEFAULT     GETDATE(),
    DateTo      DateTime,
    RoomNo      int     NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_BOOKING PRIMARY KEY (HolNo, DateFrom, RoomNo),
    -- CONSTRAINT FK_BOOKING_HOTEL FOREIGN KEY (HolNo) REFERENCES HOTEL(Code),
    CONSTRAINT FK_BOOKING_GUEST FOREIGN KEY (GuestNo) REFERENCES GUEST(GuestNo),
    CONSTRAINT FK_BOOKING_ROOM FOREIGN KEY (RoomNo, HolCode) 
          REFERENCES ROOM(RoomNo, HolCode)
)

DROP TABLE BOOKING
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please use the formatting tools to format your source code properly?

Comment: CHK_TYPE would be better served as a relationship with a `TypeRoom` table

Comment: @Frank Schmitt: This is the first time I post the question, so I don't know how to use the formatting tools.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_BOOKING_ROOM FOREIGN KEY (RoomNo,HolNo)
    REFERENCES ROOM(RoomNo,HolCode)
```

Rooms aren't uniquely identified by just a `RoomNo` so the foreign key needs to have the hotel code also. I'd also suggest, just as a stylistic point, that you try to use the same names in every table where the contents should be the same - so either `HolNo` or `HolCode`, but not *both*.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Thank you so much. It's done. I'll be careful in the name of the same variable in each table. Thank you. :D